# Changing Picture and Link with href

Tags: jquery, thumbnails, href

I try to archive following:

I have thumbnails(dynamically loaded by PHP), by clicking on them I want to change a certain picture (id = big) to the big version of the thumbnail. Around this big version there is an `<a>` tag for the lightbox jQuery script. The href of the `<a>`-Tag refers to the even bigger version of this picture.

Now I am able to change a picture with JS but how to change the href of the `<a>`-Tag which covers the image?

How the construction of the images has to look like: (I need to change href of `<a>` and the src of the image to the same link)

```
<a href="images/projekte/testprojekt/big/01.jpg" rel="lightbox[bilder]"
title="Click the X or anywhere outside the image to close">
<img src="images/projekte/testprojekt/big/01.jpg"
alt="Projekt" id="swap"/></a>
```

PHP which creates my thumbnails:

```
foreach(get_files($dir,&$endungen)  as $file) {
    $big = str_replace( 'thumbs/', 'big/', $file);
    echo "<li><img src=\"$file\" height=\"50px\" width=\"50px\" onclick=\"javascript:document.getElementById('swap').src =('/joomla/$big');\"/></li>\n";
}
```

Is there any way to do this (with jQuery)?

Comment: why don't you just add the `a` tag in the foreach?

Comment: the foreach is just for the thumbnails - the <a>-tag has to be around the preview picture (the picture which changes when I click on one thumbnails).

So: When I click one thumbnail the preview-picture changes to the same picture as I clicked on the thumb, then I click on the preview picture (now with the href changed) that lightbox opens it.